# Pass props for only one item in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am building a blog app using React. I have an Index, Feed, and Post components. My Feed comp dynamically generates a list of posts. What I want is to click on one post in the Feed and have the page render only that post. I can't figure out how to capture/pass along the props info for only the post clicked to be rendered.

For brevity here's only the relevant code:

```
    this.state = {
  view: 'feed',
  blogs: []
}

  changeView(option) {
this.setState({
  view: option
});
```

}

renderView() {
const {view} = this.state;

```
if (view === 'feed') {
  return <Feed handleClick={() => this.changeView('anypostview') blog={this.state.blogs} 
  view={this.state.view}/>
} else {
  return <Post blogs={this.state.blogs} view={this.state.view}/>
}
```

}

My click event is registering, but I don't know how to capture the props info for only the post that was clicked and send it to the Post component.

Comment: On click "page render only that post" - on the same page? (Or as separate page "router").

Comment: I would suggest `routing` for that. Dont make your app complex

Answer (score 0):

During click the specific post, pass the post to the `handleClick` and then set the state of the parent component which in this is `() => this.changeView('anypostview')`, change it to `(individualPost?: Post) => this.changeView('anypostview', individualPost)` and use that, in that case, you will not need to define or use the state `view`

Answer (score 0):

```
> blog={this.state.blogs}
```

this code will return you blank blog array .İ think you can write another function with setState for blog array

```
>   blogfunc = (blog) => {
>     this.setState({
>       blog: blog,
>     });   };
```

when you add new things in blog .Call this function and show on your page .